# Flexbox layout - Transition not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am working on the flexbox layout which has header, footer, and content.
In the content section i have multiple clickable flex items. When ever i click on anyone of the flex items, it will fill the whole width and height of the content section. I used `transition:all` for all the flex items to implement a simple animation; but its not working?

Please find the codepen link https://codepen.io/yesvin/pen/XzvdQo?editors=0100

**HTML**

```
<div class="flxWrapper">
  <div class="flxHeader">
  </div>
<div class="flxContainer">
  <div class="flxItem"></div>
  <div class="flxItem"></div>
  <div class="flxItem"></div>
  <div class="flxItem"></div>
  <div class="flxItem" style="background-color:#ff0088;"></div>
  <div class="flxItem"></div>
  <div class="flxItem"></div>
  <div class="flxItem" style="background-color:#ff8800;"></div>
</div>
  <div class="flxFooter">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  height:80vh;
}
.flxWrapper {
  width:600px;
  margin:0 auto;
  height:100%;
  border:solid 1px #ff0000;

  display:flex;
  align-items:stretch;
  justify-content:center;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.flxHeader {
  padding:20px;
  border-bottom:solid 1px #ccc;  
}
.flxFooter {
  padding:20px;
  min-height:100px;
  border-top:solid 1px #ccc;
}
.flxContainer {
  display:flex;
  flex:1;

  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width:100%;
  border:none;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
}
.flxItem {
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px;
  border:solid 1px #000;
  transistion:all 2s ease-in-out 2s;
  width:calc(100% * (1/4));
  flex:1 0 auto;
  align-self:stretch;
}

.active {
  background:rgba(125,125,125,1);
  z-index:10;
  width:calc(100% * (1/1) - 40px);  
  height:calc(100% * (1/1) - 40px);
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  align-self:stretch;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('click','.flxItem', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

**NOTE:**

1. I am using in-line style for 2 flex items, to check the active clicked flex item.
2. Width is calculated based on no. of columns per row.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the rule for `.flxItem`: "transistion" instead of "transition"

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pdMErJ